# How can i connect a html page to a Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: html, sql-server, ajax, database, sql-server-2014

I am currently working on a html web page that is supposed to visualize the data (with tables, charts, graphs...) saved in a SQL database which lies on a **local Microsoft SQL Server 2014**.

Is there a common practise to **connect the web page to this server**? I stumbled upon node.js and ajax, but i could not manage to find a proper way to get the data out of the database.

I'm completely new to this topic since i never had to back up a webpage dynamically by connecting to a database so please take me there in baby steps :)

So far, i'm using nothing else but jQuery.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And please tell me, if i'm on the completely wrong path. I'm pretty lost right now

Comment: Your question is too broad for the Q+A style of Stack Overflow and is unlikely to attract any helpful answers. I suggest you research the topic and maybe follow some online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way is to install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on your server. On it's official site there are manuals to installing and configuring it.

To connect PHP to SQL Server your will need to install proper [drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) (check PHP version, x64/x86 etc on '*details*' part of page).

Basic info how to connect to SQL Server you can find on web or, for example, [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) to connect via PDO, and [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) to connect via SQLSRV.

After on installations and configuring is done - you need to create PHP page that will take data from SQL Server and show it to user in proper way.

**EDIT**

I forgot about [SSRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) (SQL Server Reporting Services)! Here is an old good [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff660785.aspx) how to use it.

Comment: See, i didn't even know i need "another" server, i thought all of the scripts and so on had to run on the mssql server.
Thanks a lot, i will try my luck and report back!

Comment: Hey! Take a look on SQL Server Reporting Services! I add info to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

"Hi, you can do this by creating a DSN using ODBC Data Source:

1. In the Visual Studio IDE, right click on ""Data Connections"" in the Server Explorer
2. When ""Add Connection""opens, browse for the server from which the data to be pulled from and displayed.
3. Now open the ODBC Source Administrator: Start | All Programs | Control Panel |Administrative Tools | Data Sources(ODBC)
4. Select the DSN tab and click ""Add"". In the ""Create New Data Source"" window, scroll down to SQL Server Native Client 10.0
5. Select the proper parameters and click ""Finish""
6. Now open Visual Studio IDE and drag a Gridview control from the tool.
7. Click ""New data source"" from the grid and select the database from the template
8. Click ""New connection"" and select Microsoft ODBC Data source. Browse to the newly created DSN.
9. By assigning proper binding column to the grid the data can be displayed in the html grid.
   "